# Group-Based Role Management Identity Framework 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I may get some various options for this, but I have basic "out of the box" ASP.NET Identity Framework 2 enabled application. I currently have the standard tables of AspNetRoles, AspNetUsers, and AspNetUserRoles, and so on.

That said, the requirements for our application (in addition to other things) is to have users assigned to *groups* not *roles*. We have in prior projects called these "RoleTemplates", examples may include something like "Admin" or "ReportUser" who would only have access to reports. I have already set up a way to associate a Roles table with a RoleTemplates table in the form of "RoleTemplateRoles", and a web UI to add or remove roles to a role template, essentially giving permissions to Admins or particular groups, as opposed to the users directly.

I anticipate my next step would be to set up an "AspNetUserRoleTemplates" table, associating Users with Role Templates as opposed to Roles. But from there, I'm not sure what I may need to change in the application itself - some key areas I've identified seem to be the EDMX model itself representing this relationship, as well as the ConfigureAuth method and IdentityModels.cs, which looks something like this and is not customized much at the moment.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

What would be recommended for designing such capabilities? I imagine I may need to customize some of the code that was built into a standard MVC5 application to look at Role Templates to derive Roles, I'm just not sure if I may be following the best practices and where it would be best to customize this functionality while keeping the application secure and easy to maintain.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between a role and a group?

Comment: Roles describe capabilities. Groups describe relationships. Admittedly, Microsoft has mangled the meanings over the years by essentially conflating the two, but something like "Administrators" is a *group*. An ability a user in the "Administrators" group might have, such as "CreateUser" is a role.

Comment: Chris basically answered it before I got to it - the built-in Identity framework capabilities does exactly what we want for this application (except we likely won't use e-mail to sign in). The only thing it doesn't do, is provide us with groups we can assign users to, which we could derive Roles for users from. So Users would not directly have "CreateUser" privileges/roles, but they might be considered part of an Administrator group/template which does have these rights.

Comment: I'm going to be trying something like this out, which seems pretty close to what I am trying to accomplish (the screencaps at the end describe it pretty well).

http://johnatten.com/2014/08/10/asp-net-identity-2-0-implementing-group-based-permissions-management/

If it works, I'll answer my own question - but I'm curious what others have done or suggest with their experience.

Comment: John Atten knows his onions and more when it comes to Identity and I'm pretty sure your answer will lie there - try this link too http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=6750249